# How come Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors doesn't work on HTMLElements?

Tags: javascript

If you transverse the prototype chain, you'll see at the bottom (top?) is `Object.prototype`, therefore I figured they would behave like ordinary objects. However, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` does not give you an object with all the properties you'll see associated with the object when viewing it in the console via `console.dir`. How can this be?

```js
for (let property of Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(document))) {
  console.log(property)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the wrong thing - can you post example of code that produces the unexpected result

Comment: @JaromandaX done

Comment: `document` is an instance of `HTMLDocument` - I guess you were expecting the properties of an instance of `Document`?

Comment: @Shablcu - do you know what `getOwnPropertyDescriptors` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. This is because many of the properties on `HTMLElement`'s are actually [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) prototype functions.

There's a lot of magic going on behind the curtain of the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) to turn the almost-English `document.body.style = 'background: pink;'` into a rendered graphics update. Using getters & setters aids reactivity patterns and removes the memory waste of redundant property construction on thousands of `HTMLElement`'s.

Example:

```
// Class with prototype getter
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.year = new Date().getFullYear()
  }
  get time() {
    return Date.now();
  }
}
console.dir(new Thing());
// > Prints a JSON representation including `Thing#time` and `Thing#year`

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(new Thing()));
/* 
 > Prints an object with *only* the `#year` descriptor 
   because `#time` is a prototype function, not a property
*/
```

Comment: FYI, notice the `<>` icon in editor. You can make a snippet that readers can run and test

Comment: I see, that's interesting that getters in the prototype chain get shown as properties of the currently viewed object in the dev tools.

Comment: @Rajesh The Stack Overflow console doesn't behave the same as a browser console. Specifically, it doesn't show the getter properties in `console.dir`, which is the enigma of this question. Readers are best served by copying & pasting the code snippet into their browser console

Comment: @Mason I agree. It's especially interesting that the console automatically runs all the getters when logging an `HTMLElement`. But it makes sense, as that's much more convenient for developers than clicking-to-run every getter